# Distance between incentre and centre of circle tangent to other sides

Tags: geometry, circles

I was solving some geometry problems before I was stuck onto a problem. The problem says that if tangents from the $A$ point outside the circle are drawn, what would be the distance between the incentre of the triangle formed by $A$ and the points where the tangents touch the cricles. I tried using $PA\cdot PB=PT^2$ but arrived nowhere.

[image]

Comment: Give some more information about radius of circle. A figure describing problem would be preffered so we can use the same notations as you have

Comment: The incentre will lie on the circle itself so I think the distance would simply be the radius of circle.

Comment: sir how to draw figure in stackexchange

Comment: @user300518 You can't unfortunately, you have to insert image instead

Comment: I added a picture for you. Please, try to readapt the notation of the problem (mainly, the formula you are mentioning) to the one in the picture. For your information, I used [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/) to draw it.

Answer (score 1):

According to your notation, $AP_1 BP_2$ is a cyclic quadrilateral (its vertices lie on a circle having $AB$ as a diameter), hence $\widehat{AP_1 P_2}=\widehat{ABP_2}$ and that is enough to prove that the incenter of $AP_1 P_2$ is just the intersection between $AB$ and the original circle, namely $C$. We also have: 
$$\frac{1}{2}\widehat{P_1 B C}=\widehat{P_1 P_2 C}=\frac{1}{2}\widehat{P_1 P_2 A}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\widehat{P_2 A B}\right)=\frac{\pi-\widehat{P_2 A P_1}}{4},$$
hence $CP_1 = 2\,BP_1\sin\left(\frac{\widehat{P_1 B C}}{2}\right)$ can be easily described in terms of $AB$ and $r=BP_1$, for instance.